# how to reconnect redis connection after some give time?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

If Redis connection is down then how to reconnect Redis after some given time.
I want to use Redis retry_strategy.

```
const redisClient =  redis.createClient({
host: redisConfig.host, 
port: redisConfig.port, 
retry_strategy: (options) => {
  if (options.error) {
      const errorMsg = options.error;
      let resMsg = new responseMsg(rm.i18nConfig.defaultLocale, "handler", {});
      resMsg.errorRes(errorMsg, null, 'Redis Error: '+errorMsg, (err, data)=> {});
  }    
}
```

})

The following code is reconnecting the Redis after a given time as pass in return.

```
const redisClient =  redis.createClient({
host: redisConfig.host, 
port: redisConfig.port, 
retry_strategy: (options) => {
  if (options.error) {
      const errorMsg = options.error;
      let resMsg = new responseMsg(rm.i18nConfig.defaultLocale, "handler", {});
      resMsg.errorRes(errorMsg, null, 'Redis Error: '+errorMsg, (err, data)=> {});
  } 
return 100000;
}
```

})

Note:- 100000 is millisecond.

But the main problem is that during this reconnection process I m not able to call any API, but after a successful connection, I m able to call the APIs.

Note:- If I remove the return, then it will not try to reconnect Redis, but I can do the API call

Requirement:- I want to call API during Redis connection retry_strategy process when I m passing return value option in the callback

Comment: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis - Is that the client you're using? If so, there's a pretty solid example there.

Comment: @NickLeBlanc That example is working fine, but for example, if I m passing 15 min in return. So for that 15 min. I m not able to call any API, it is giving timeout, but if the connection is established after 15 then I m able to call API.

But I want to call API during that 15 min duration which I m passing in return.

Comment: Hi @PreetamPatel were you able to figure this out - I have the same issue that I'm running into. in terms of being able to do other things (api call) while reconnect happens in background.. thanks